# find with char* variable doesnt work

Tags: c++, find, stdmap

I'd like to know why I have a memory error with this:

The problem appears on char* value = aMap.find(keync)->second

If I put manualy char* value = "key0" it works!!!

```
using std::map;
map <char*, char*> aMap;

void search(const char* key) {
    const int LEN = strlen(key);

    char* keync = new char[LEN];

    for (int i= 0; i < LEN; i++) {
       keync[i] = key[i];
    }

    char* value = aMap.find(keync)->second;

    printf("%s", value);

    delete[] keync;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    a["key0"] = "value0";
    search("key0");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What aren't you using `std::string`? The conversion from a string literal to `char*` is deprecated, don't do it. At the least use `const char*`. Also, the map is going to be comparing pointer values, not strings, you need to provide a custom comparator. (Or just use `std::string`, again.) Stop doing manually memory management, wrap things up. (`std::vector` exists for this, or, again, `std::string`.) And lastly, do remember the terminator for C-strings. (Maybe [a book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) would be helpful.)

Comment: I'm under PalmOS I haven't access to std::string

Comment: @Okami: You need to make one, then. Resource use needs to be separated from resource management. Make a class with the Big Three, then use that class, don't try to mix them together. You can wrap it around `std::vector`. And if you don't have that, there's the Big Three class you need to make. The moment you have a need to manually delete a resource outside of managing it, you've done something wrong.

Comment: I said bulshit, there is std::string on PalmOS

Comment: @GMan: You need to put your comments into an answer, so we can vote it.

Comment: @Martin: Meh. :) I like to let other people get reputation points sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add 1 to the length of the array:

```
char* keync = new char[LEN+1];
```

You're null terminating outside the string you allocated.

(Also, are you initialising aMap?)

Comment: Good catch on the off-by-one.  The `map` initialization is fine.  It just default-constructs it.

Comment: I'm initializing the map.
My char* is only "key0"
Should I put the terminator '\0' ?

Comment: @Okami, "key0" is equivalent to `{'k', 'e', 'y', '0', '\0'}`.  So the null-terminator is already there.

Comment: ok, by your explanation with or without putting '\0' the size will be LEN+1.
Weird C stuff :-/

Comment: @Okami, no, if you put `"key0\0"` (there's no reason to do this), it would be,  `{'k', 'e', 'y', '0', '\0', '\0'}`.  The `strlen` would still be the same (4 in this example), since that's the number of characters before the first NUL-terminator.  You have to allow room for a single NUL-terminator, for a total size of LEN + 1 (5 in the example).

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed, you are much better off using `std::string` for this. Now, for the actual problem why you are not able to find the string is because you are storing *pointers* in the map i.e. the key to the map is a pointer variable. You inserted a `char*` in to the map but when you are trying to find you are doing a `new` again. This ia a *totally different* pointer (although the string value they point is same) hence your lookup will fail.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious issue is the:

```
delete keync;
```

Because you used new [], it should be:

```
delete[] keync;
```

Comment: ok I missed that, but the problem occours on:
char* value = aMap.find(keync)->second;

Answer (score 0):

You are better using std::string instead of char*. Another plus of using std::string is that you will avoid memory leaks.

The other solution will be to provide map with a comparator function, otherwise they will not compare the content of each char*, but instead the address pointed. The following example was adapted from Sgi's [std::map](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) documentation:

```
struct comp
{
  bool operator()(char* s1, char* s2) const
  {
    return strcmp(s1, s2) < 0;
  }
};

map<char*, char*, comp> stringMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well look for starters you should drop all the char* stuff and use `std::string`, this would probably make your problem go away.

FYI:
`keync[LEN] = '\0';` // this is wrong and will be one past the end of the allocated array

The copying of the key parameter is wrong. Try this on for size:

```
using std::map;
map <char*, char*> aMap;

void search(const char* key) {
    const int LEN = strlen(key);

    char* keync = const_cast<char*>(key);

    char* value = aMap.find(keync)->second;

    printf("%s", value);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    aMap["key0"] = "value0";
    search("key0");

    return 0;
}
```

The problem you were having is because you were allocating `keync` as `strlen(key)` which doesn't count the null terminator. In your copy loop you were then overwriting the null terminator with the last char of `key`.

The whole idea of copying the input string is wrong and I have replaced it with a const cast in my solution as it makes more sense (as far as that goes).

Comment: Ok I corrected that:
keync[LEN] = '\0';

The problem still goes on.

Answer (score 0):

```
using std::map;
map <char*, char*> aMap;
```

first of all, this map won't compare strings (inside of search) but addresses. So basicly you won't find anything with std::map::search by typing string literals.

```
void search(const char* key) {
    const int LEN = strlen(key);

    char* keync = new char[LEN];

    for (int i= 0; i < LEN; i++) {
       keync[i] = key[i];
    }
```

at this moment you have unterminated string, but it doesn't matter in your code

```
    char* value = aMap.find(keync)->second;
```

here you're performing search by comparing pointers values (addresses), so returned map iterator is invalid (it's equal aMap.end()), so either it has null or unallocated pointer as `second` member

```
    printf("%s", value);

    delete[] keync;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    a["key0"] = "value0";
    search("key0");

    return 0;
}
```

I hope it explains you why should you use std::string instead of char *